# How to call Json objects dynamically?

Tags: javascript, json

var house = {'floor':{'one':'3 people','two':'1 people'}}
    var tmp = 'one';
and I want to call like this..

```
console.log(house.floor.tmp) // expecting '3 people' result
```

tmp value will get from somewhere dynamically but it's not working. How can I solve this?

Comment: You're technically using an object literal, not JSON. JSON is a serialization format that's based on a subset of JavaScript's object literal syntax.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
console.log(house.floor[tmp]);
```

Should work for you.

In this scenario you are just using indexing notation to reference the object property, since the engine won't resolve `tmp` to the value of `'one'` using dot notation.